# Can jQuery be used with Ext.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

After reading some of the jQuery vs ext js questions here and google search result, my understanding is that ext js is a UI building library and jQuery is a more fundamental javascript framework. I've used jQuery for a while now. It's pretty cool but in general a better (much better) javascript.

So my question is: how easy is it to use jQuery for DOM navigation/manipulation and Ext.js for UI in the same project?

There is a page on jQuery website. But the demo is too simple and the external links to Ext.js are all dead.

I'm sure it's possible, but what sort of problems and challenges would I be facing?

You might be wondering why I want to do this. Well, the Ext.js set of UI just looks much better/more polished/more feature rich then jQuery UI. I'm particularly interested in the grid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using both libraries side by side is not an issue in the technical way (just add the jquery within a script-tag, that's it!). However, you should not use jQuery for ExtJS' stuff or vice versa. Well, unless you know exactly what you do.

The actual issue can be DOM manipulations (jQuery or ExtJS Core) outside of an ExtJS component that affect an existing component.

So, in a nutshell: You can use DOM manipulations when it will not affect the ExtJS components.  Otherwise use the proper way within the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have no problem do this stuff... Make Ext.js your main jQuery library and jQuery as the data manipulation library for the DOM.

There would be no problem or conflicts because jQuery is compatible with other javascript libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Well you dont need both the libraries to live together.. Extjs has DOM manipulation api too probably not as vast as jquery but it does have the basic stuff.

Coming to Jquery, jquery has UI building  APIs too if not rolled into the library there are vast no of extensions for all kinds of problems. Just try googling whatever UI you are building now with respect to jquery and you will find a library for sure.. There is [jquery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) too that lets you generate HTML markup from a template defined by you and applying data objects (json) to it.. Jquery has a vast community too so most of your questios or concerns will be addressed by the community almost instantly..

So yea my suggestion would be to choose one library and stick to it and contribute to the library if there are many missing features..

Lastly I would suggest you choose Jquery.. It rocks.. period..

Comment: I'm not going to abandon jquery because I quite like it and it's apparently popular. Just like the ext js UI better.

Comment: I say jQuery (UI) doesn't rock when it comes to providing usable and versatile, yet stable controls out of the box. Period!